# NSMutableDictionary and NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

Hello I am making a card game for ios,  It is the kings drinking game,

To do this I use the following code to fill a dictionary

```
 cardValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



for (card1 = 1; card1 <= 13; card1++) {

    card2 = card1;

    [cardValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:card2]];
    [cardValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:card2]];
    [cardValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:card2]];
    [cardValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:card2]];
}
 dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:cardValues forKeys:cardKeys];
```

cardvalues is a NSMutableArray that goes through 1 to 13, 4 times for the 4 suits of cards

cardkeys is a NSArray that is filled with the names of the the 52 cards e.g.

```
  cardKeys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
@"clubace",
@"diamondace",
@"heartace",
@"spadeace",

@"club2",
@"diamond2",
@"heart2",
@"spade2",
```

and so on through the array.

I am having a problem getting the cardvalues matched to numbers for displaying the rule that follows that card being drawn

For example if the 5 of hearts is drawn I will display a message drink for 5 seconds, the same for any other 5

I was hoping that somone could tell me how i would get this done.

Any help is appreciated

Thanking You

Comment: What logic do you currently have for checking this?  This sounds like you should just check the existence of the card number in cardValues.

Comment: currently i have no logic to do that, how would i check the card number in cardValues

Comment: Well, I'd first recommend heeding @dreamlax's advice.  Beyond that, I'd first consider changing your index so you can avoid searches where possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think that a better approach would be to have a `PlayingCard` class that contains both the suit and the value of the card. You can then have a single array containing 52 `PlayingCard` objects. You can pull any of these 52 `PlayingCard` objects at random from an array (and/or remove them from the array). The `PlayingCard` class could also have an `UIImage` property that you could use to draw the card to the screen.

If you find yourself storing related data in two or more separate containers, chances are you will be better off encapsulating that data in a class and using a single container to store instances of your class.